# Backup and upgrade

Tags: monerod, backup, update

It's getting cold and its a time to turn on my heater/miner again ;-)

I saw that this machine is still running Ubuntu 14.04. I think it would be time to upgrade/reinstall the entire machine at that point.

What do I need to backup? Which files/directories?

After that I will wipe out the hard disk and reinstall Ubuntu 16.04.3 server. Then install Monero again and then restore the files you suggested before I restart to mine.

Besides the backup, do I need to take care of anything else?

Answer (score 2):

You should back up the `~/.bitmonero` directory (which contains the blockchain) and your wallet files (the `<wallet name>`, `<wallet name>.keys`, and (though not needed) `<wallet name>.txt`.

Aside from that, there's little to worry about.

Comment: I did the first part and installed the new server. I forgot where I got all the pieces. Can you please give me a hint.

Comment: Well, `~/.bitmonero` is the full path for that (hidden dir in home dir). Wallets can be saved wherever, as long as you run the `monero-wallet-cli` with `--wallet-file` flag.  For example, you could save the wallet files in `~/.wallets`, a hidden directory.  And you'd run `.monerod --wallet-file ~/.wallets/<wallet name>`.  Otherwise, IIRC, wallet files are stored in the same dir as `monero-wallet-cli`.  And `monero-wallet-cli` can be wherever you want it to be.

Comment: I installed the monerod and the monero-wallet-cli with my wallet info, which I copied into a directory mywallet. There are now a couple of things:

Comment: 1. monero-v0.11.1.0/monerod 
2017-11-26 11:04:52.954 [P2P3]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1
521     SYNCHRONIZED OK

seems the daemon is working ok

Comment: 2. My wallet shows me a balance: 5.530000000000, unlocked balance: 5.530000000000 
Does that mean, I got 5.53 PLUS 5.53 or 5.53 BUT all is locked???

Comment: 3. Mining shows me sudo /home/ronald/cpuminer-multi/minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://monerohash.com:3333 -u 47***Lr2N -p x -t 4
Using JSON-RPC 2.0
Starting Stratum on stratum+tcp://monerohash.com:3333
4 miner threads started, using 'cryptonight' algorithm.
 ...retry after 10 seconds
 ...retry after 10 seconds

Comment: 1.  Yes.  2.  You've got 5.53 and it's able to be spent now.  Search SE for what "locked balance" means.  3.  The command looks right, but anyway it's well outside the scope of this question. I will say that you don't need the daemon or wallet installed on your comp for it to work.  Perhaps hop on IRC/Freenode on #monero-pools for help.

Comment: 3. started to mine after I left my computer sometimes later. Thanks for getting me going again.